How to reuse @types/request in @cypress/request module
As request module is depreacted, I want to switch to @cypress/request npm module. @cypress/request is a fork repo request module.
I want to use @cypress/request in my typescript project. While building my project, It is throwing below error:
error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@cypress/request'.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/cypress__request` if it exists or add a new declaration 
(.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@cypress/request';`

I tried installing npm i --save-dev @types/cypress__request however there is not such types repo. Does anyone know how to overcome this problem? Is there any way to reuse request module's type definitions while using @cypress/request?
Thanks in advance.
